# XA Transactions and work outside it's context

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, xa

I'm getting a message through MQ to my EJB application and it's a XA Transaction. After I receive message I need to send some http requests and send back the response(This will be a RMI call).
My concern is that because of these requests queue listener might shutdown (Taking long time to reply by http requests).
Solutions I found were to do the work in a server managed thread or do the work in another EJB since it will work out side the context of current working XA Transaction(Not sure about this exactly).
Please let me know what is the best solution.